# Keep getting errors while importing from csv file to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
import mysql.connector as mysql

marathons = []

with open ("marathon_results.csv") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    next(data)
    for rij in data:
        year = rij[0],
        winner = rij[1],
        gender = rij[2],
        country = rij[3],
        time = rij[4],
        marathon = rij[5],
        marathons.append((year, winner, gender, country, time, marathon))

conn = mysql.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     password=""
)

c = conn.cursor()

create_database_query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS marathon_file'
c.execute(create_database_query)

c.execute('USE marathon_file')
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS winners(
                year INT(100),
                winner VARCHAR(255),
                gender VARCHAR(255),
                country VARCHAR(255),
                time TIME,
                marathon VARCHAR(255)
                )
            """)
print('CSV-bestand in de MySQL-database aan het laden...')

insert_query = "INSERT INTO winners(year, winner, gender, country, time, marathon) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, &s);"

c.executemany(insert_query, marathons)
c.commit()

print('Bestand succesvol geladen!')
```

So i have this code above trying to get a certain .csv file from my venv to mysql. made a list from the data and skipped the first line (since those were headers) and tried to import it to mysql. But i keep getting the following Error:

```
CSV-bestand in de MySQL-database aan het laden...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py in to_mysql(self, value)
    179         try:
--> 180             return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
    181         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in _process_params(self, params)
    430 
--> 431             res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
    432             res = [escape(i) for i in res]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    430 
--> 431             res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
    432             res = [escape(i) for i in res]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py in to_mysql(self, value)
    181         except AttributeError:
--> 182             raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a "
    183                             "MySQL type".format(type_name))

TypeError: Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/yc/mz4bq04s7wngrglphldwpwfc0000gn/T/ipykernel_17482/929148642.py in <module>
     38 insert_query = "INSERT INTO winners(year, winner, gender, country, time, marathon) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, &s);"
     39 
---> 40 c.executemany(insert_query, marathons)
     41 c.commit()
     42 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in executemany(self, operation, seq_params)
    665                 self._rowcount = 0
    666                 return None
--> 667             stmt = self._batch_insert(operation, seq_params)
    668             if stmt is not None:
    669                 self._executed = stmt

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in _batch_insert(self, operation, seq_params)
    607                         tmp, self._process_params_dict(params))
    608                 else:
--> 609                     psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
    610                     tmp = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, tmp)
    611                     if psub.remaining != 0:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in _process_params(self, params)
    433             res = [quote(i) for i in res]
    434         except Exception as err:
--> 435             raise errors.ProgrammingError(
    436                 "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
    437         else:

ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tuple' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

I probably missed some () or brackets or am i missing something else? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these lines:

```py
        year = rij[0],
        winner = rij[1],
        gender = rij[2],
        country = rij[3],
        time = rij[4],
        marathon = rij[5],
```

The trailing commas cause `year`, `winner`, `gender` and so on to be created as 1-tuples. It's the same as writing

```py
        year = (rij[0],)
        winner = (rij[1],)
        # and so on...
```

Delete the trailing commas and try again.

Comment: Thanks, also found a syntax error with using my cursor in the commit statement. Now it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your sql comad had a & instead of a %.

I additionally simplified the data loop

```
import csv
import mysql.connector as mysql

marathons = []


with open ("test2.csv") as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    next(data)
    marathons =  [tuple(row) for row in data]

conn = mysql.connect(
     host="localhost",
     user="root",
     password=""
)

c = conn.cursor()

create_database_query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS marathon_file'
c.execute(create_database_query)

c.execute('USE marathon_file')
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS winners(
                year INT(100),
                winner VARCHAR(255),
                gender VARCHAR(255),
                country VARCHAR(255),
                time TIME,
                marathon VARCHAR(255)
                )
            """)
print('CSV-bestand in de MySQL-database aan het laden...')

insert_query = "INSERT INTO winners(year, winner, gender, country, time, marathon) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"

c.executemany(insert_query, marathons)
conn.commit()

print('Bestand succesvol geladen!')
```